# Change column data position by order

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

tbl

```
SEQ1 | SEQ2 | D1                  | D2       
---: | ---: | :------------------ | :--------
   1 |    1 | 12-SEP-19 4:10:00 PM| 12-SEP-19 4:14:00 PM
   2 |    2 | 12-SEP-19 4:20:00 PM| 12-SEP-19 4:36:00 PM
   3 |    3 | 12-SEP-19 4:30:00 PM| 12-SEP-19 4:52:00 PM
   4 |    4 | 12-SEP-19 4:35:00 PM| 12-SEP-19 5:16:00 PM
   5 | null | 12-SEP-19 4:40:00 PM| null
   6 | null | 12-SEP-19 4:45:00 PM| null     
   7 | null | 12-SEP-19 4:50:00 PM| null    
   8 | null | 12-SEP-19 5:00:00 PM| null      
   9 | null | 12-SEP-19 5:10:00 PM| null      
   10| null | 12-SEP-19 5:20:00 PM| null
```

I want change order d2 base on d1 data like this

```
SEQ1 | SEQ2 | D1                  | D2       
---: | ---: | :------------------ | :--------
   1 |    1 | 12-SEP-19 4:10:00 PM| 12-SEP-19 4:14:00 PM
   2 | null | 12-SEP-19 4:20:00 PM| null
   3 | null | 12-SEP-19 4:30:00 PM| null
   4 | null | 12-SEP-19 4:35:00 PM| null
   5 |    2 | 12-SEP-19 4:40:00 PM| 12-SEP-19 4:36:00 PM
   6 | null | 12-SEP-19 4:45:00 PM| null     
   7 | null | 12-SEP-19 4:50:00 PM| null    
   8 |    3 | 12-SEP-19 5:00:00 PM| 12-SEP-19 4:52:00 PM  
   9 | null | 12-SEP-19 5:10:00 PM| null      
   10|    4 | 12-SEP-19 5:20:00 PM| 12-SEP-19 5:16:00 PM
```

How can order table and change position row data?
Please help me...

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=14e1af4979a7d717b1d5589d21ea7282)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following ordering logic:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(D2, D1)
```

Your updated query:

```
SELECT
    SEQ1,
    SEQ2,
    D1,
    D1
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(D2, D1);
```

### Demo

 (updated)